# Extjs store insert roweditor

Tags: extjs, extjs6

The setup:
I have a grid with a roweditor plugin. On the toolbar I have a "add new" button to insert a new row.
The problem:
When I'm trying to add a new record my store.insert(0, rec), doesn't seems to add the record on the 0 index.

My view:

```
Ext.define("app.view.partners.Partners",{
extend: "Ext.grid.Panel",
alias: 'widget.partners',

requires: [
    "Admin.view.partners.PartnersController",
    "Admin.view.partners.PartnersModel"
],
height: 700,
controller: "partners",
viewModel: {
    type: "partners"
},
bind: {
    store: '{partners}'
},
title: "Partners List",
columns: [
    { header: 'id', dataIndex: 'id', hidden: true},
    { header: 'Partner', dataIndex: 'Partner', flex: 3,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            allowBlank: false
        }
    }

],

tbar: [{
    text: 'Add record',
    iconCls: 'fa fa-plus-square green',
    handler: 'onAddClick'
}],
selType: 'rowmodel',
plugins: [{

    ptype: 'rowediting',
    clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
    pluginId: 'partnersRowEditingPlugin',
    autoCancel: false,
    listeners: {
       edit: 'onEditClick',
       canceledit: function(rowEditing, context) {
            // Canceling editing of a locally added, unsaved record: remove it
            if (context.record.phantom) {
                context.store.remove(context.record);
            }
        }
    }
  },{ptype: 'bufferedrenderer'},
    {ptype: 'gridfilters'}
  ]
});
```

My viewmodel:

```
Ext.define('app.view.partners.PartnersModel', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
alias: 'viewmodel.partners',
stores: {
    partners:{
        model: 'app.model.Partners',
        storeId: 'partners',
        autoLoad: true,
        sorters: [{
            property: 'id',
            direction: 'DESC'
        }],
        proxy:{
            type: 'ajax',
            // load remote data using HTTP
            url: 'read.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                idProperty: 'id',
                rootProperty: 'data',
                totalProperty:'total'
            }
        } 
    }
}

});
```

and in the viewcontroller:

```
onAddClick: function(){
    var rec = new app.view.partners.PartnersModel({});
    //var rec = new new Admin.model.Partners({});

    this.isNewRecord = true;

    var store = this.getView().getStore();

    store.insert(0, rec);

    this.getView().getPlugin(controllerName + 'RowEditingPlugin').startEdit(0,0);
}
```

[here is a console.log after store.insert(0,rec)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Th7.jpg)

It appears that the store does the insert, but it is inserted last. I can see it added on the grid as the last record.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You've asked the store to be sorted, so inserting at a particular index is meaningless, it will be inserted wherever is the correct sorted position.

Comment: You are absolutely correct!!! I've missed that, completely. Thanks a lot mate!